# Generate PHP switch based on folder content

Tags: php, file, loops, switch-statement

Let us say I have a folder containing 3 files; file1.php, file2.php, file3.php.
In the same folder, I have index.php, which I want to generate switch cases for each file.

```
$files = array();
$folder = opendir(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
while ($file = readdir($folder)) { 
    if (strpos($file, '.php') !== false && $file !== 'index.php') { 
        array_push($files, $file);  
    }
}

$switch = $_GET['component'];
switch($switch) {
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        case str_replace('.php', '', $file):        include_once($file);                break;
    }   
}
```

What I would like my cases to look like in the end:

```
$switch = $_GET['component'];
switch($switch) {
        case file1:     include_once('file1.php');              break;
        case file2:     include_once('file2.php');              break;
        case file3:     include_once('file3.php');              break;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I have a proper overview of what you're trying to achieve in the long run here... so ... just to confirm:  You have a number of files, and the files represent components.  Depending on which component is provided in the URL, you want to include a different file?  And you can only have a single component on the page, not multiple components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um... Seems convoluted to me.

```
if( in_array($_GET['component'].".php",glob("*.php")) && $_GET['component'] != "index")
    include_once($_GET['component'].".php");
```

Comment: +1 to you.if it really works its very good. but if you could just do check the value of `$_GET['component']` and also check if the file exists it would be perfect.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed, but with minor mods :)

Comment: @imsiso That would be unsafe, allowing for access to other files such as `../hax.php`

Comment: ok but all I wanted to said is about handling errors to prevent give the hackers data with our errors.

Comment: @imsiso If the file doesn't exist, it wouldn't be in the `glob` array, so it wouldn't pass the test.

Comment: yes but what about the permission to read? and what about bad thing in `$_GET['component']` and what about if `$_GET['component']` was not set?